# unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') - Flask app with uwsgi

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a python flask app in below structure

```
Admin
   |-app
       | -__init__.py
   |-wsgi.py
```

My wsgi.py contents is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from app import app
from app import views


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Contents of **init**.py in app package

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

I started wsgi as below

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi
```

The server is started successfully but I can error in startup log as below

```
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 709
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 256
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:8080 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x7fd7eb6000d0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 70195, cores: 1)
```

Similar issues were posted but whatever solutions offered for those issues are already in my code. I am not able to find why I am getting this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"Callable not found is the issue" (not the import error, i suspect). Change:

`uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi`

into this

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app
```

or

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --protocol=http --module wsgi --callable app
```

see [here, search for 'flask deploy'](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example).

Comment: uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app worked for me

Comment: for me as well. @GG_Python thank you, it helped alot!

Comment: This one helped me ...Thanks!

Comment: Not for me. I am still getting NoAppException

Comment: Since this answer seems to help many people, I suspect your setup/configuration might be different, or missing something. Post a question with the server code you're trying to run, will try to help.