# Why my python file returns unable to load app in uwsgi flask?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have read the below questions related to `uwsgi` and interestingly enough nothing has helped so far:

- [Flask and uWSGI - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030809/flask-and-uwsgi-unable-to-load-app-0-mountpoint-callable-not-found-or-im)
- [uwsgi-nginx-flask: unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774122/uwsgi-nginx-flask-unable-to-load-app-0-mountpoint-callable-not-found-or-i)
- [unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') - Flask app with uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476441/unable-to-load-app-0-mountpoint-flask-app-with-uwsgi)

It seems that I need to import app as `application` as `uWSGI` tries to find the application variable.

```
from tf_api import create_app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = application()
    application.run()
else:
    print("---------------------->", __name__)
    application = application()
```

When I run the below command:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:80 --protocol=tcp -w wsgi:app
```

It goes to `else` part and outputs:

```
----------------------> wsgi
2020-02-20 14:25:22,168 [tf_core] Initialized! [testing=False]
2020-02-20 14:25:22,176 [tf_api] {"msg": "Initialized! Testing: False", "logger_name": "tf_api", "log_level": "DEBUG", "timestamp": "2020-02-20T14:25:22.176664"}
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 27143, cores: 1)
```

Some logs are printed from the application then it prints `no app loaded`!

**When I** put `application.run(host='0.0.0.0')` in else, it seems that application starts running but on flask default port `5000` not on `uWSGI`:

```
----------------------> wsgi
2020-02-20 14:36:57,333 [tf_core] Initialized! [testing=False]
2020-02-20 14:36:57,339 [tf_api] {"msg": "Initialized! Testing: False", "logger_name": "tf_api", "log_level": "DEBUG", "timestamp": "2020-02-20T14:36:57.339723"}
 * Serving Flask app "tf_api" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
2020-02-20 14:36:57,405 [werkzeug]  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-02-20 14:36:57,406 [werkzeug]  * Restarting with stat
unable to load configuration from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tf_api/uwsgi
```

**BUT it** gives an error related to `unable to load configuration from`. `created_app` returns `app`. What do you guys think is the reason for not finding the `app` in `uswgi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in `uwsgi` command I used `-w wsgi:app` I had to rename below code:

```
application = application()
```

**to:**

```
app = application()
```

Without `app.run()`, as `uWSGI` itself runs the flask application and it is not needed.